# Remove integer shift of phase difference

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

I wanted to remove the integer shift from the phase difference `theta(k1,k2)` between two images. As you can see from the figure below, it's a sawtooth signal.

[image]

Thus to get a decimal shift only phase difference, I need to subtract the integer shift from the original phase. That's `theta_decimal=theta-theta_int`. Since the integer shift(`IntShift=[dx; dy]`) was determined using phase correlation, thus according to this paper: *Sub-pixel Shift Estimation of Image based on the Least Squares Approximation in Phase Region* by Fujimoto, Fujisawa and Ikehara *(Proceedings of 26th European Signal Processing Conference, EUSIPCO '16, pp. 91–95. IEEE, 2016 [PDF](http://www.eurasip.org/Proceedings/Eusipco/Eusipco2016/papers/1570251532.pdf))*, Equation (14), the integer shift can be removed by finding the slope of phase correlation shift. That is, `theta_decimal=theta-(a*k1+b*k2)`, where `a` and `b` is the slope of the integer shift.

Result from the subtracting will give phase difference as follow:

[image]

The question is how do I obtain the slope in the first hand?
Here's part of my matlab code which I failed to get accurate shift:

```
    f = im2double(imread('cameraman.tif')); %Reference image
    deltar = -3.48574;
    deltac = 8.73837;
    phase = 2;
    [nr,nc]=size(f);
    Nr = ifftshift((-fix(nr/2):ceil(nr/2)-1));
    Nc = ifftshift((-fix(nc/2):ceil(nc/2)-1));
    [Nc,Nr] = meshgrid(Nc,Nr);
    g = ifft2(fft2(f).*exp(1i*2*pi*(deltar*Nr/nr+deltac*Nc/nc))).*exp(-1i*phase); %Shifted image

    [m, n]=size(f);

    F=(fft2(double(f)));
    G=(fft2(double(g)));

    R=(F.*conj(G))./abs(F.*conj(G));
    r=(ifft2(R));

    [~,w] = max(r(:));
    [del_hat2p, del_hat1p] = ind2sub(size(r),w);

    if del_hat1p<m/2, del_hat1p=-(del_hat1p-1); else, del_hat1p=m-(del_hat1p-1); end
    if del_hat2p<n/2, del_hat2p=-(del_hat2p-1); else, del_hat2p=n-(del_hat2p-1); end

    IntShift=[del_hat1p;del_hat2p];

    theta=angle(F)-angle(G);
    R=exp(1j*theta); 
    theta=atan2(imag(R),real(R)); %Here's the theta
    [ap, bp, theta_int]=lsa(theta);
    theta_decimal=theta-theta_int
    figure; surf(theta);
    figure; surf(theta_decimal); %Still not right

    %actual case should be like this thatap=theta-(integer shift)
    %thetapp=theta-(IntShift); %You can refer equation 14 in the paper
    %surf(thetapp);

function [ a, b, hat ] = lsa( theta )
[m, n]=size(theta);
[M,N] = meshgrid(1:m,1:n);
X = [M(:), N(:)];
B=regress(theta(:), X);
a=B(1);
b=B(2);
hat=reshape(X*B,m,n);
end
```

How can this be done correctly in matlab? Thanks!